# Counting up with nested arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, nested, grid

I am attempting to count up the index 1 values of the arrays within nested arrays. My desired output is:

```
[ [ [ 0, 0 ], [ 0, 1], [ 0, 2 ] ] ]
```

However I am getting the following as my output:

```
[ [ [ 0, 2 ], [ 0, 2 ], [ 0, 2 ] ] ]
```

Here is the code I am running, I am assuming the issue falls in the second for loop:

```
let width = 3
let height = 1
var grid = [];
let y = 0

for(var i=0; i<height; i++) {
    grid[i] = new Array(width).fill([0,0])
}
let currentRow = grid[0]

for (let j = 0; j<grid[0].length; j++){
  currentRow[j][1] = j
}
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your code to

```
    let width = 3;
    let height = 1;
    var grid = [];
    let y = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < height; i++) {
      grid[i] = new Array(width);
      for (let j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
        grid[i][j] = [0, 0];
      }
    }
    let currentRow = grid[0];
    
    for (let j = 0; j < grid[0].length; j++) {
      currentRow[j][1] = j;
    }
```

when you use `grid[i] = new Array(width).fill([0,0])` you are saving one instance of `[0,0]` in your `grid[i]` array ,it means `currentRow[0]==currentRow[1]` is `true`, so when you change the `currentRow[j][1]` all of `currentRow` elements get changed, in your last step of second loop you change `currentRow[2][1]=2` so all of `currentRow` elements get changed in this way.

Comment: What alternatives exist to get it to count up?